# Redirect if page != login or register? Klein

Tags: php, template-engine, klein-mvc

today I have a question about Klein and I am asking becasue there isn't much documentation on this library on the internet. I want to redirect the user back to /login if they are on any page other than "/login" or "/register" AND they arent logged i, below I have tried:

```
$this->klein->respond('GET', '!@^/login|register', function ($request, $response, $service, $app) {
            if (!Latrina::getLibrary('latrina.user.user')->loggedIn()) {
                $response->redirect('/login')->send();
            }
        });
```

It works, but it redirects to /login if they are on /register which is pretty annoying because it disables them from signing up..

Comment: the docs isn't clear about that, and I don't know klein-router. __But__ the problem seems to be here: `'!@^/login|register'`. I'd try `'!@^/login|/register'` _or_ even `'!@^/login|!@^/register'`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't personally verified that the $request param to this callback is a string -- it may be an object or array, with the URL you need to check as a property. But this general logic is what you're looking for:

```
$this->klein->respond('GET', '!@^/login|register', function ($request, $response, $service, $app) {
        if (!Latrina::getLibrary('latrina.user.user')->loggedIn()) {
            if (strpos($request, 'login') !== false) {
                $response->redirect('/login')->send();
            } else {
                $response->redirect('/register')->send();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't work, it seems none of the function parameters pass the page the visitors viewing.